# AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'hitbox'

Tags: python, pygame, attributeerror

I've been teaching myself PyGame following Clear Code's video on YouTube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QU1pPzEGrqw&list=PL0Kxjlg6sfuEz5MCJYqmA8Kop54LHEcmv&index=51&t=9087s

but i hit a wall and no matter how many times i re-watch the video i cant find a single character out of place or understand why his code is running without adding the attribute like my script is requesting me to do.

Here are the scripts i believe that one would need to help me troubleshoot as well as the error output im receiving:

**error output**

```
[Running] python -u "c:\Devver\main.py"
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.10.5)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Devver\main.py", line 30, in <module>
    game.run()
  File "c:\Devver\main.py", line 24, in run
    self.level.run()
  File "c:\Devver\level.py", line 91, in run
    self.visible_sprites.update()
  File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 539, in update
    sprite.update(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Devver\enemy.py", line 64, in update
    self.move(self.speed)
  File "c:\Devver\entity.py", line 15, in move
    self.collision('horizontal')
  File "c:\Devver\entity.py", line 23, in collision
    if sprite.hitbox.colliderect(self.hitbox):
AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'hitbox'

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.502 seconds
```

**main.py**

```
import pygame, sys
from level import Level
from settings import *


class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        # general setup
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGTH))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Outer Heaven')
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        self.level = Level()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

            self.screen.fill('black')
            self.level.run()
            pygame.display.update()
            self.clock.tick(FPS)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game()
    game.run()
```

**enemy.py**

```
import pygame
from settings import *
from entity import Entity
from support import *

class Enemy(Entity):
    def __init__(self,monster_name,pos,groups,obstacle_sprites):

        # general setup
        super().__init__(groups)
        self.sprite_type = 'enemy'

        # graphics setup
        self.import_graphics(monster_name)
        self.status = 'idle'
        self.image = self.animations[self.status][self.frame_index]
        
        # movement setup
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos)
        self.hitbox = self.rect.inflate(0,-10)
        self.obstacle_sprites = obstacle_sprites

        # enemy stats
        self.monster_name = monster_name
        monster_info = monster_data[self.monster_name]
        self.health = monster_info['health']
        self.exp = monster_info['exp']
        self.speed = monster_info['speed']
        self.attack_damage = monster_info['damage']
        self.resistance = monster_info['resistance']
        self.attack_radius = monster_info['attack_radius']
        self.notice_radius = monster_info['notice_radius']
        self.attack_type = monster_info['attack_type']

    def import_graphics(self,name):
        self.animations = {'idle':[],'move':[],'attack':[]}
        main_path = f'./graphics/monsters/{name}/'
        for animation in self.animations.keys():
            self.animations[animation] = import_folder(main_path + animation)

    def get_player_dd(self,player):
        enemy_vec = pygame.math.Vector2(self.rect.center)
        player_vec = pygame.math.Vector2(player.rect.center)
        distance = (player_vec - enemy_vec).magnitude()

        if distance > 0:
            direction = (player_vec - enemy_vec).normalize()
        else:
            direction = pygame.math.Vector2()

        return (distance,direction)

    def get_status(self,player):
        distance = self.get_player_dd(player)[0]

        if distance <= self.attack_radius:
            self.status = 'attack'
        elif distance <= self.notice_radius:
            self.status = 'move'
        else:
            self.status = 'idle'

    def update(self):
        self.move(self.speed)
    
    def enemy_update(self,player):
        self.get_status(player)
```

**player.py**

```
import pygame
from settings import *
from support import import_folder
from entity import Entity

class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self,pos,groups,obstacle_sprites,create_attack,destroy_attack,create_magic):
        super().__init__(groups)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('C:/Devver/graphics/test/player.png').convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos)
        self.hitbox = self.rect.inflate(0,-26)

        # graphics setup
        self.import_player_assets()
        self.status = 'down'

        # movement
        self.attacking = False
        self.attack_cooldown = 400
        self.attack_time = 0
        self.obstacle_sprites = obstacle_sprites

        # weapon
        self.create_attack = create_attack
        self.destroy_attack = destroy_attack
        self.weapon_index = 0
        self.weapon = list(weapon_data.keys())[self.weapon_index]
        self.can_switch_weapon = True
        self.weapon_switch_time = None
        self.switch_weapon_cooldown = 200

        # magic
        self.create_magic = create_magic
        self.magic_index = 0
        self.magic = list(magic_data.keys())[self.magic_index]
        self.can_switch_magic = True
        self.magic_switch_time = None
        self.switch_magic_cooldown = 100

        # stats
        self.stats = {'health': 100, 'energy': 60, 'attack': 10, 'magic': 4, 'speed': 5}
        self.health = self.stats['health'] * 0.5
        self.energy = self.stats['energy'] * 0.8
        self.exp = 123
        self.speed = self.stats['speed']

    def import_player_assets(self):
        character_path = './graphics/player/'
        self.animations =    {'up': [], 'down': [], 'left': [], 'right': [],
            'right_idle': [], 'left_idle': [], 'up_idle': [], 'down_idle': [],
            'right_attack': [], 'left_attack': [], 'up_attack': [], 'down_attack': []}
        
        for animation in self.animations.keys():
            full_path = character_path + animation
            self.animations[animation] = import_folder(full_path)

    def input(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        # movement input
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.direction.y = -1
            self.status = 'up'
        elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.direction.y = 1
            self.status = 'down'
        else:
            self.direction.y = 0

        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.direction.x = 1
            self.status = 'right'
        elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.direction.x = -1
            self.status = 'left'
        else:
            self.direction.x = 0
        
        # attack input
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and not self.attacking:
            self.attacking = True
            self.attack_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            self.create_attack()

        # magic input
        if keys[pygame.K_LCTRL] and not self.attacking:
            self.attacking = True
            self.attack_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            style = list(magic_data.keys())[self.magic_index]
            power = list(magic_data.values())[self.magic_index]['power'] + self.stats['magic']
            cost = list(magic_data.values())[self.magic_index]['cost']
            self.create_magic(style,power,cost)

        # switching weapons
        if keys[pygame.K_q] and self.can_switch_weapon:
            self.can_switch_weapon = False
            self.weapon_switch_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

            if self.weapon_index < len(list(weapon_data.keys())) - 1:
                self.weapon_index += 1
            else:
                self.weapon_index = 0

            self.weapon = list(weapon_data.keys())[self.weapon_index]
        
        # switching magic
        if keys[pygame.K_e] and self.can_switch_magic:
            self.can_switch_magic = False
            self.magic_switch_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

            if self.magic_index < len(list(magic_data.keys())) - 1:
                self.magic_index += 1
            else:
                self.magic_index = 0
            
            self.magic = list(magic_data.keys())[self.magic_index]

    def get_status(self):

        #idle status
        if self.direction.x == 0 and self.direction.y == 0:
            if not 'idle' in self.status and not 'attack' in self.status:
                self.status = self.status + '_idle'

        if self.attacking:
            self.direction.x = 0
            self.direction.y = 0
            if not 'attack' in self.status:
                if 'idle' in self.status:
                    self.status = self.status.replace('_idle','_attack')
                else:
                    self.status = self.status + '_attack'
        
        else:
            if 'attack' in self.status:
                self.status = self.status.replace('_attack','')

    def cooldowns(self):
        current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if self.attacking:
            if current_time - self.attack_time >= self.attack_cooldown:
                self.attacking = False
                self.destroy_attack()

        if not self.can_switch_weapon:
            if current_time - self.weapon_switch_time >= self.switch_weapon_cooldown:
                self.can_switch_weapon = True
        
        if not self.can_switch_magic:
            if current_time - self.magic_switch_time >= self.switch_magic_cooldown:
                self.can_switch_magic = True

    def animate(self):
        animation = self.animations[self.status]

        # loop over the frame index
        self.frame_index += self.animation_speed
        if self.frame_index >= len(animation):
            self.frame_index = 0
        
        # set the image
        self.image = animation[int(self.frame_index)]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = self.hitbox.center)

    def update(self):
        self.input()
        self.cooldowns()
        self.get_status()
        self.animate()
        self.move(self.speed)
```

**entity.py**

```
import pygame

class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,groups):
        super().__init__(groups)
        self.frame_index = 0
        self.animation_speed = 0.15
        self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2()

    def move(self,speed):
        if self.direction.magnitude() != 0:
            self.direction = self.direction.normalize()

        self.hitbox.x += self.direction.x * speed
        self.collision('horizontal')
        self.hitbox.y += self.direction.y * speed
        self.collision('vertical')
        self.rect.center = self.hitbox.center

    def collision(self,direction):
        if direction == 'horizontal':
            for sprite in self.obstacle_sprites:
                if sprite.hitbox.colliderect(self.hitbox):
                    if self.direction.x > 0: # moving right
                        self.hitbox.right = sprite.hitbox.left
                    if self.direction.x < 0: # moving left
                        self.hitbox.left = sprite.hitbox.right

        if direction == 'vertical':
            for sprite in self.obstacle_sprites:
                if sprite.hitbox.colliderect(self.hitbox):
                    if self.direction.y > 0: # moving down
                        self.hitbox.bottom = sprite.hitbox.top
                    if self.direction.y < 0: # moving up
                        self.hitbox.top = sprite.hitbox.bottom
```

**level.py**

```
import pygame
from settings import *
from tile import Tile
from player import Player
from debug import debug
from support import *
from random import choice
from weapon import Weapon
from ui import UI
from enemy import Enemy

class Level:
    def __init__(self):

        # get the display surface
        self.display_surface = pygame.display.get_surface()

        # sprite group setup
        self.visible_sprites = YSortCameraGroup()
        self.obstacle_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

        # attack sprites
        self.current_attack = None

        # sprite setup
        self.create_map()

        # user interface
        self.ui = UI()

    def create_map(self):
        layouts = {
            'boundary': import_csv_layout('./map/map_FloorBlocks.csv'),
            'grass': import_csv_layout('./map/map_Grass.csv'),
            'objects': import_csv_layout('./map/map_Objects.csv'),
            'entities': import_csv_layout('./map/map_Entities.csv')
        }
        graphics = {
            'grass': import_folder('./graphics/grass'),
            'objects': import_folder('./graphics/objects')
        }

        for style,layout in layouts.items():
            for row_index, row in enumerate(layout):
                for col_index, col in enumerate(row):
                    if col != '-1':
                        x = col_index * TILESIZE
                        y = row_index * TILESIZE
                        if style == 'boundary':
                            Tile((x,y),[self.obstacle_sprites],'invisible')
                        if style == 'grass':
                            random_grass_image = choice(graphics['grass'])
                            Tile((x,y),[self.visible_sprites, self.obstacle_sprites],'grass',random_grass_image)
                        
                        if style == 'objects':
                            surf = graphics['objects'][int(col)]
                            Tile((x,y),[self.visible_sprites, self.obstacle_sprites],'objects',surf)

                        if style == 'entities':
                            if col == '394':
                                self.player = Player(
                                    (x,y),
                                    [self.visible_sprites],
                                    self.obstacle_sprites,
                                    self.create_attack,
                                    self.destroy_attack,
                                    self.create_magic)
                            else:
                                if col == '390': monster_name = 'bamboo'
                                elif col == '391': monster_name = 'spirit'
                                elif col == '392': monster_name = 'raccoon'
                                else: monster_name = 'squid'
                                Enemy(monster_name,(x,y),[self.visible_sprites],[self.obstacle_sprites])

    def create_attack(self):
        self.current_attack = Weapon(self.player,[self.visible_sprites])

    def create_magic(self,style,power,cost):
        print(style)
        print(power)
        print(cost)

    def destroy_attack(self):
        if self.current_attack:
            self.current_attack.kill()
        self.current_attack = None

    def run(self):
        # update and draw the game
        self.visible_sprites.custom_draw(self.player)
        self.visible_sprites.update()
        self.visible_sprites.enemy_update(self.player)
        self.ui.display(self.player)

class YSortCameraGroup(pygame.sprite.Group):
    def __init__(self):

        # general setup
        super().__init__()
        self.display_surface = pygame.display.get_surface()
        self.half_width = self.display_surface.get_size()[0] // 2
        self.half_height = self.display_surface.get_size()[1] // 2
        self.offset = pygame.math.Vector2()

        # creating the floor
        self.floor_surface = pygame.image.load('./graphics/tilemap/ground.png').convert()
        self.floor_rect = self.floor_surface.get_rect(topleft = (0,0))

    def custom_draw(self,player):

        # getting the offset
        self.offset.x = player.rect.centerx - self.half_width
        self.offset.y = player.rect.centery - self.half_height

        # drawing the floor
        floor_offset_pos = self.floor_rect.topleft - self.offset
        self.display_surface.blit(self.floor_surface,floor_offset_pos)

        # for sprite in self.sprites():
        for sprite in sorted(self.sprites(),key = lambda sprite: sprite.rect.centery):
            offset_pos = sprite.rect.topleft - self.offset
            self.display_surface.blit(sprite.image,offset_pos)

    def enemy_update(self,player):
        enemy_sprites = [sprite for sprite in self.sprites() if hasattr(sprite,'sprite_type') and sprite.sprite_type == 'enemy']
        for enemy in enemy_sprites:
            enemy.enemy_update(player)
```

**settings.py**

```
# game setup
WIDTH    = 1280 
HEIGTH   = 720
FPS      = 60
TILESIZE = 64

# UI
BAR_HEIGHT = 20
HEALTH_BAR_WIDTH = 200
ENERGY_BAR_WIDTH = 140
ITEM_BOX_SIZE = 80
UI_FONT = './graphics/font/joystix.ttf'
UI_FONT_SIZE = 18

# general colors
WATER_COLOR = '#71ddee'
UI_BG_COLOR = '#222222'
UI_BORDER_COLOR = '#111111'
TEXT_COLOR = '#EEEEEE'

# ui colors
HEALTH_COLOR = 'red'
ENERGY_COLOR = 'blue'
UI_BORDER_COLOR_ACTIVE = 'gold'

# weapons
weapon_data = {
    'sword': {'cooldown': 100, 'damage': 15, 'graphic':'./graphics/weapons/sword/full.png'},
    'lance': {'cooldown': 400, 'damage': 30, 'graphic':'./graphics/weapons/lance/full.png'},
    'axe': {'cooldown': 300, 'damage': 20, 'graphic':'./graphics/weapons/axe/full.png'},
    'rapier': {'cooldown': 50, 'damage': 8, 'graphic':'./graphics/weapons/rapier/full.png'},
    'sai': {'cooldown': 80, 'damage': 10, 'graphic':'./graphics/weapons/sai/full.png'},
            }

# magic
magic_data = {
    'flame': {'power': 5,'cost': 20,'graphic':'./graphics/particles/flame/fire.png'},
    'heal' : {'power': 20,'cost': 10,'graphic':'./graphics/particles/heal/heal.png'}
            }

# enemy
monster_data = {
    'squid': {'health': 100,'exp':100,'damage':20,'attack_type': 'slash', 'attack_sound':'./audio/attack/slash.wav', 'speed': 3, 'resistance': 3, 'attack_radius': 80, 'notice_radius': 360},
    'raccoon': {'health': 300,'exp':250,'damage':40,'attack_type': 'claw',  'attack_sound':'./audio/attack/claw.wav','speed': 2, 'resistance': 3, 'attack_radius': 120, 'notice_radius': 400},
    'spirit': {'health': 100,'exp':110,'damage':8,'attack_type': 'thunder', 'attack_sound':'./audio/attack/fireball.wav', 'speed': 4, 'resistance': 3, 'attack_radius': 60, 'notice_radius': 350},
    'bamboo': {'health': 70,'exp':120,'damage':6,'attack_type': 'leaf_attack', 'attack_sound':'./audio/attack/slash.wav', 'speed': 3, 'resistance': 3, 'attack_radius': 50, 'notice_radius': 300}}
```

**weapon.py**

```
import pygame

class Weapon(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, player,groups):
        super().__init__(groups)
        direction = player.status.split('_')[0]

        # graphic
        full_path = f'./graphics/weapons/{player.weapon}/{direction}.png'
        self.image = pygame.image.load(full_path).convert_alpha()

        # placement
        if direction == 'right':
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midleft = player.rect.midright + pygame.math.Vector2(0,16))
        elif direction =='left':
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midright = player.rect.midleft + pygame.math.Vector2(0,16))
        elif direction == 'up':
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midbottom = player.rect.midtop + pygame.math.Vector2(-10,0))
        else:
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midtop = player.rect.midbottom + pygame.math.Vector2(-10,0))
```

**ui.py**

```
import pygame
from settings import *

class UI:
    def __init__(self):
        
        # general
        self.display_surface = pygame.display.get_surface()
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(UI_FONT,UI_FONT_SIZE)

        # bar setup
        self.health_bar_rect = pygame.Rect(10,10,HEALTH_BAR_WIDTH,BAR_HEIGHT)
        self.energy_bar_rect = pygame.Rect(10,34,ENERGY_BAR_WIDTH,BAR_HEIGHT)

        # convert weapon dictionary
        self.weapon_graphics = []
        for weapon in weapon_data.values():
            path = weapon['graphic']
            weapon = pygame.image.load(path).convert_alpha()
            self.weapon_graphics.append(weapon)

        # convert magic dictionary
        self.magic_graphics = []
        for magic in magic_data.values():
            path = magic['graphic']
            magic = pygame.image.load(path).convert_alpha()
            self.magic_graphics.append(magic)
    
    def show_bar(self,current,max_amount,bg_rect,color):
        # draw the background
        pygame.draw.rect(self.display_surface,UI_BG_COLOR,bg_rect)

        # converting stats to pixels
        ratio = current / max_amount
        current_width = bg_rect.width * ratio
        current_rect = bg_rect.copy()
        current_rect.width = current_width

        # drawing the bar over the background
        pygame.draw.rect(self.display_surface,color,current_rect)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.display_surface,UI_BORDER_COLOR,bg_rect,3)

    def show_exp(self,exp):
        text_surf = self.font.render(str(int(exp)),False,TEXT_COLOR)
        x = self.display_surface.get_size()[0] - 20
        y = self.display_surface.get_size()[1] - 20
        text_rect = text_surf.get_rect(bottomright = (x,y))
        
        pygame.draw.rect(self.display_surface,UI_BG_COLOR,text_rect.inflate(20,20))
        self.display_surface.blit(text_surf,text_rect)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.display_surface,UI_BORDER_COLOR,text_rect.inflate(20,20),3)

    def selection_box(self,left,top,has_switched):
        bg_rect = pygame.Rect(left,top,ITEM_BOX_SIZE,ITEM_BOX_SIZE)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.display_surface,UI_BG_COLOR,bg_rect)
        if has_switched:
            pygame.draw.rect(self.display_surface,UI_BORDER_COLOR_ACTIVE,bg_rect,3)
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(self.display_surface,UI_BORDER_COLOR,bg_rect,3)
        return bg_rect

    def weapon_overlay(self,weapon_index,has_switched):
        bg_rect = self.selection_box(10,630,has_switched) # weapon
        weapon_surface = self.weapon_graphics[weapon_index]
        weapon_rect = weapon_surface.get_rect(center = bg_rect.center)
        self.display_surface.blit(weapon_surface,weapon_rect)

    def magic_overlay(self,magic_index,has_switched):
        bg_rect = self.selection_box(80,635,has_switched) # magic
        magic_surface = self.magic_graphics[magic_index]
        magic_rect = magic_surface.get_rect(center = bg_rect.center)
        self.display_surface.blit(magic_surface,magic_rect)

    def display(self,player):
        self.show_bar(player.health,player.stats['health'],self.health_bar_rect,HEALTH_COLOR)
        self.show_bar(player.energy,player.stats['energy'],self.energy_bar_rect,ENERGY_COLOR)

        self.show_exp(player.exp)

        self.weapon_overlay(player.weapon_index,not player.can_switch_weapon)
        self.magic_overlay(player.magic_index,not player.can_switch_magic)
```

**tile.py**

```
from tkinter import Y
import pygame
from settings import *

class Tile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos,groups,sprite_type,surface = pygame.Surface((TILESIZE,TILESIZE))):
        super().__init__(groups)
        self.sprite_type = sprite_type
        self.image = surface
        if sprite_type == 'objects':
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (pos[0],pos[1] - TILESIZE))
        else:
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos)
        self.hitbox = self.rect.inflate(0,-10)
```

Comment: I cannot run your code, because you didn't provide the file **settings.py**, **weapon.py** and ui.py**

Answer (score 0):

I cannot run your code because you didn't provide all your files, but the error likely occurred because you didn't define `hitbox` in the `__init__()`, which means that in the function `collision()` you're trying to access this variable before it has been created.

To avoid those problems, define all variables that you will use across different methods in the `__init__()` of your class

Comment: Added the missing files. If it throws any other errors let me know. If i define hitbox in my entinty.py like so: `__init__(self,groups,hitbox)` will that solve the issue?

Comment: Or are you saying to add below like so:
`__init__(self,groups):
self.hitbox = <definition>`

Thank you for taking the time to help btw :)

Comment: Either only option 2, or you can combine option 1 and 2 like so: `__init__(self, groups, hitbox): self.hitbox = hitbox `